# gaierror: [Errno -5] when using SSHLibrary

Tags: docker, robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am running robotframework inside a Docker container. When I ssh to `srv1` from the CLI of the container it works, but when I run the following robotframework test script, I get `gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname`. Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

```bash
# robot sshtest.robot
==============================================================================
Sshtest
==============================================================================
Connecting to another machine                                         | FAIL |
gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sshtest                                                               | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

This is the robotframework test script.

```bash
*** Settings ***
Library     SSHLibrary


*** Variables ***
${REMOTEIP}     srv1
${USERNAME}     admin
${PASSWORD}     admin@123


*** Test Cases ***
Connecting to another machine
    Open Connection    host=${REMOTEIP}
    Login    username=${USERNAME}    password=${PASSWORD}
```

Comment: maybe sshlibrary ignores your .ssh/config or you are using RF as another account so that ssh config is not there ?